# Python syntax error - backslash in psql queries with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I have a small python script. I want to execute a psql command with the librairy psycopg2:

```
query = "\COPY ( select * from 'schema'.structure) TO 'path' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

But I have a syntaxe error with the `\COPY`.
I have tried to change it with `''` and `\\` but nothing seems to work. I don't want to use `cur.copy_from`.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: `\copy`  **only** works in `psql` it's not a general [SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) and can't be used through Python. If Python offers a  specific API for that, you will have to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `psycopg2` for `COPY`ing with custom SQL, you have to use [`copy_expert`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert). Assuming your query works, this way:

```py
with open(file_path, "w") as outfile:
    cur.copy_expert("COPY (select * from 'schema'.structure) TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER", outfile)
```

You have to give a writeable file as second parameter and use `TO STDOUT` inside your query.

Comment: It worked ! I also saw you can use cur.copy_from and cur.copy_to. But with cur.copy_expert I had no issue with the permission rights. Thanks !